# SQL Server Parse decimal to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I have a table in SQL Server 2017. In this table date stores as a decimal in next format:

**20180717164540.2200000**

**YYYYMMDDhhmiss.nnnnnnn**

4 digits for the year, 2 digits for a calendar month, 2 digits for a day of a month, 2 digits for a 24-hour based hour of the day in UTC, 2 digits for a minute of an hour, 2 digits for seconds of a minute, and fractional seconds.

My aim is to transform this format into DateTime and store it in another table in a database.
So my question is how to convert this format to DateTime format in SQL Server. As far as I know, you can not create custom date format like in Oracle.

I tried a lot of times with **FORMAT** AND **CONVERT** MSSQL functions but it not gonna work.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(22), DECIMALCOLUMN), 'YYYYMMDDhhmiss') FROM SOURCE-TABLE;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The best solution by far would be to stop storing datetime values like this. Use the correct datatype and this is not an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were really close with your FORMAT idea. FORMAT gives you an NVARCHAR output, which you can explicitly CAST as a DATETIME2(7) (which maintains your precision level).

```
DECLARE @dateWannaBe DECIMAL(21,7) = 20180717164540.2200000;

SELECT CAST(FORMAT(@dateWannaBe,'####-##-## ##:##:##.#######', 'en-US') AS DATETIME2(7)) AS ActualDateTime2;

+-----------------------------+
|       ActualDateTime2       |
+-----------------------------+
| 2018-07-17 16:45:40.2200000 |
+-----------------------------+
```

EDIT: Added the culture parameter to the FORMAT function per @JeroenMostert's comment.

Comment: I'd make this slightly safer by explicitly specifying `en-US` as the culture in `FORMAT`, so the decimal separator always comes out as `.`. Otherwise this code will fail under (e.g.) `SET LANGUAGE French`.

Comment: Excellent observation, @JeroenMostert. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

a lot of stuffing

```
declare @dt decimal(30,8)   = 20180717164540.2200000

select  @dt, convert(datetime2, 
                     stuff(
                           stuff(
                                 stuff(
                                       convert(varchar(30), @dt), 
                                       9, 0, ' '), 
                                 12, 0, ':'), 
                            15, 0, ':')
                      )

/* RESULT
20180717164540.22000000 2018-07-17 16:45:40.2200000
*/
```

Comment: Unlike answers using `DATETIME`, this solution will not lose precision on the fractional seconds. Even if your destination type is actually `DATETIME` and not `DATETIME2`, you can just convert the result of this again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @date DECIMAL (30,7) =20180717164540.2200000

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date),1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date),5,2)
+ '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date),7,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date),9,2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date),11,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date),13,2) + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date),16,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `SUBSTRING()` function with `stuff()` :

```
select dateadd(ss, datediff(ss, 0, cast(stuff(stuff(substring(cast(@date as varchar(30)), 9, 20), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as datetime2)), 
                   substring(cast(@date as varchar(10)), 1, 8)
              )
. . .
```

Comment: @JeroenMostert. . . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TIME DECIMAL(38,8)

SET @TIME = '20180717164540.2200000'



SELECT CAST([DT] AS DATETIME) FROM(
SELECT LEFT(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR),4)  + 
SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR),5,2)  + 
SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR),7,2)  + ' ' +
SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR),9,2) + ':'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR),11,2)  + ':' +
SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR),13,2) AS DT
) AS X
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). In this context it means `VARCHAR(30)`, which happens to be big enough, but relying on that is bad form.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING` and `RIGHT`

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(22) = '20180717164540.2200000'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, 
               LEFT(@str,4)+
               SUBSTRING(@str,5,2)+
               SUBSTRING(@str,7,2)+' '+
               SUBSTRING(@str,9,2)+':'+
               SUBSTRING(@str,11,2)+':'+
               SUBSTRING(@str,13,2)+'.'+
               RIGHT(@str,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stuff and use DateTime2 instead of DateTime:

```
select 
  cast(stuff(stuff(stuff(
    cast(mydate as varchar(30)),
  13,0,':'),
  11,0,':'),
  9,0,' ') as datetime2) as myDateTime from myTable;
```